# How to add a node in closure used by a StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-serialization

I've the following closure:

```
def myData = {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    OneEntry() {
        SecondInnerEntry()
    }
}
```

I can serialize its XML representation with `StreamingMarkupBuilder` (import omitted):

```
System.out << XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(myData))
```

Which give me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OneEntry>
  <SecondInnerEntry/>
</OneEntry>
```

But now i want to add a new entry before calling the `bind()` method of `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OneEntry>
  <FirstInnerEntry/>
  <SecondInnerEntry/>
</OneEntry>
```

How can i do this (*i.e* manipulate the closure to insert a new node, I don't want to recreate the whole `myData` to just insert one element) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing `myData` (as [erimerturk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8227816/6509) says), or performing two passes, ie:

1. generate the xml with `myData`
2. parse this xml with `XmlParser`
3. insert a node at the desired location
4. write this new xml out

I don't think this is possible..  The question boils down to:

> How can I insert statements in the middle of an existing closure

To which the simple answer is "You can't"*

(* it might be possible to do what you are trying by means of an AST Transformation, but I get the feeling it may not be possible in this case)

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I found a solution for my case but didn't really found the ideal answer. Your reply is quite interesting about groovy limitation, I need to dive deeper in Groovy one of these days...

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is working for my specific case, but does not fully answer the question (*i.e* walk and modify the closure)

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def dataToInsert = {
    FirstInnerEntry()
}

def myData = {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    OneEntry() {
        mkp.yield dataToInsert
        SecondInnerEntry()
    }
}

System.out << XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(myData))
```